# Setting up SSL for credit card payments

Tags: php, apache, drupal, ssl, https

I have just developed a credit-card processing form using Drupal, the form communicates with the Payway API (a payment processing API provided by my bank).

I have purchased an SSL certificate with my host, and I know have an HTTPS server on my hosting account. What do I do to make all my forms run through HTTPS? Sorry I am new to SSL and am completely clueless in this matter.

I've tried copying my drupal site into my httpsdocs folder but it runs extremely slow when I access it through https://

Any help or direct would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to force HTTPS on a web server is through a .htaccess file on the root of your web server. Then you can apply HTTPS only to the folders you need.

If you are using Drupal, there is likely already a .htaccess file on the root of your website that you can edit. Here's a simple guide on what needs to be added to the file:
http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/force-ssl-htaccess.html

Comment: Great, I think that's exactly what I need, thanks! Just a quick question though, do I need to transfer any files to my httpsdocs folder? Or can it all stay in my httpdocs folder?

Comment: @Sina Sounds like you're running Plesk. At least in the newer versions, you domain can be configured to use one directory for SSL and non-SSL content~ or to require separate folders. You'll have to check on your plesk control panel.